Differences in Generics Between RxJS Documentation and GitHub Code
I'm reading up on RxJS and noticed that for some functions, there are differences in the documentation vs. the Github code, even though the documentation seems to be directly generated from the code.
Two examples
catchError docs:
catchError(
  selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => O
): OperatorFunction<T, T | ObservedValueOf<O>>

catchError code:
export function catchError<T, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(
  selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => O
): OperatorFunction<T, T | ObservedValueOf<O>>;

concat docs:
concat(
  ...inputs: [...ObservableInputTuple<T>]
): Observable<T[number]>

concat code:
export function concat<T extends readonly unknown[]>(
  ...inputs: [...ObservableInputTuple<T>]
): Observable<T[number]>;

This is only for some functions, so I guess that it is intended and I'm missing something. Can someone explain why the generics in the function are omitted in these cases?

In the examples where the type param is omitted, there is no possible ambiguity when inferring the types from the arguments.  The times the type param is visible are when something makes it ambiguous, like if a a single generic param is used in an optional argument or not in any arguments at all.  Why they do this, I have no idea.
